# SQL query to breakdown the rows into multiple 1hr intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table like below which has start and end times with different intervals and the Quantity corresponding to those intervals. I need to have a query which will calculate quantity based on time intervals of from now() to 5hrs, now() to 10hrs, now() to 15hrs

Eg:
In the below image say now the time is 12:00PM and so now() to 5hrs is 12:00 to 5:00PM -> Row nos (S No) from 3 to 6 and partially 7 will qualify and the Qty should be as below:
3rd row -> 10 to 12:30 which has 4556 Qty for 2.30Hrs (150mins) but I need half n Hour of it because now() to 12:30 it is 30mins. So I only need 30mins of 4556 Qty -> 4556*30/150
4,5,6 rows all qualify fully -> so 4905 Qty
7th row -> For 4:00PM t 6:00PM -> 2Hrs the Qty is 3645. I need till 5:00PM ie., 1hr so 3645/2
So my total Qty for now() to 5hrs is 7638

| S No | interval start | interval end | Qty | time_diff_Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11/23/2022 8:30 | 11/23/2022 9:45 | 3045 | 75 |
| 2 | 11/23/2022 9:45 | 11/23/2022 10:00 | 0 | 15 |
| 3 | 11/23/2022 10:00 | 11/23/2022 12:30 | 4556 | 150 |
| 4 | 11/23/2022 12:30 | 11/23/2022 13:00 | 0 | 30 |
| 5 | 11/23/2022 13:00 | 11/23/2022 15:45 | 4905 | 165 |
| 6 | 11/23/2022 15:45 | 11/23/2022 16:00 | 0 | 15 |
| 7 | 11/23/2022 16:00 | 11/23/2022 18:00 | 3645 | 120 |
| 8 | 11/23/2022 18:00 | 11/23/2022 18:45 | 0 | 45 |

How do I achieve this is mySQL using SQL query?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSJtF.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). paste your data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: Could you please provide input and expected output? in text format as @ThorstenKettner suggested.

Comment: S No interval start  interval end    Qty  time_diff_Min
1 11/23/2022 8:30        11/23/2022 9:45             3045  75
2 11/23/2022 9:45 11/23/2022 10:00       0   15
3 11/23/2022 10:00 11/23/2022 12:30      4556  150
4 11/23/2022 12:30 11/23/2022 13:00        0   30
5 11/23/2022 13:00 11/23/2022 15:45     4905 165
6 11/23/2022 15:45 11/23/2022 16:00       0 15
7 11/23/2022 16:00 11/23/2022 18:00    3645 120
8 11/23/2022 18:00 11/23/2022 18:45       0 45

Comment: I'm unable to format the data :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume NOW = `2022-11-24 05:30:00`, which is 15 minutes passed last `interval_end` showed in the image.
2. Generate a series of minute timestamps from NOW all the way back to the earliest `interval_start`
3. Calculate `qty_per_minute` = `qty` / `time_diff_min` (or use `timestampdiff()` to calculate minutes between `interval_start` and `interval_end`
4. Calculate the nth 5-hour interval from NOW and aggregate to each 5-hour interval.

```
set @now = '2022-11-24 05:30:00';
set @@cte_max_recursion_depth=10000;

with recursive cte(interval_ts) as (
select min(interval_start) as interval_ts from entries
union all
select timestampadd(minute, 1, interval_ts)
  from cte
 where interval_ts < timestampadd(minute, -1, @now)),
cte_entry_per_minute as (
select e.SNo,
       e.interval_start,
       e.interval_end,
       e.qty,
       (e.qty / timestampdiff(minute, e.interval_start, e.interval_end)) as qty_per_min,
       c.interval_ts,
       (timestampdiff(minute, c.interval_ts, @now)-1) div 300 as interval_5hr_from_now
  from entries e,
  lateral (select interval_ts from cte
            where interval_ts >= e.interval_start
              and interval_ts <  e.interval_end) as c)
select interval_5hr_from_now,
       min(interval_ts)                          as interval_start,
       max(timestampadd(minute, 1, interval_ts)) as interval_end,
       sum(1)                                    as interval_minutes,
       sum(qty_per_min)                          as total_qty
  from cte_entry_per_minute
 group by 1
 order by 1 desc;
```

Result (`qty` rounding error exptected):

```
interval_5hr_from_now|interval_start     |interval_end       |interval_minutes|qty       |
---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------+
                    4|2022-11-23 08:30:00|2022-11-23 09:30:00|              60| 2436.0000|
                    3|2022-11-23 09:30:00|2022-11-23 14:30:00|             300| 7840.4520|
                    2|2022-11-23 14:30:00|2022-11-23 19:30:00|             300| 8074.6380|
                    1|2022-11-23 19:30:00|2022-11-24 00:30:00|             300|13564.9050|
                    0|2022-11-24 00:30:00|2022-11-24 05:15:00|             285| 8971.0080|
```

Sample data as below:

```
create table entries (
    SNo     int,
    interval_start  timestamp,
    interval_end    timestamp,
    qty             int,
    time_diff_min   int);

truncate table entries;

insert into entries
values
( 1, '2022-11-23  8:30:00', '2022-11-23  9:45:00', 3045,  75),
( 2, '2022-11-23  9:45:00', '2022-11-23 10:00:00',    0,  15),
( 3, '2022-11-23 10:00:00', '2022-11-23 12:30:00', 4556, 150),
( 4, '2022-11-23 12:30:00', '2022-11-23 13:00:00',    0,  30),
( 5, '2022-11-23 13:00:00', '2022-11-23 15:45:00', 4905, 165),
( 6, '2022-11-23 15:45:00', '2022-11-23 16:00:00',    0,  15),
( 7, '2022-11-23 16:00:00', '2022-11-23 18:00:00', 3645, 120),
( 8, '2022-11-23 18:00:00', '2022-11-23 18:45:00',    0,  45),
( 9, '2022-11-23 18:45:00', '2022-11-23 21:30:00', 8067, 165),
(10, '2022-11-23 21:30:00', '2022-11-23 21:45:00',    0,  15),
(11, '2022-11-23 21:45:00', '2022-11-24 00:00:00', 7698, 135),
(12, '2022-11-24 00:00:00', '2022-11-24 00:30:00',    0,  30),
(13, '2022-11-24 00:30:00', '2022-11-24 03:45:00', 7253, 195),
(14, '2022-11-24 03:45:00', '2022-11-24 04:00:00',    0,  15),
(15, '2022-11-24 04:00:00', '2022-11-24 05:15:00', 1718,  75);
```